# Cannot browse VPN files by IP

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, pptp

I have created a Windows VPN using the built in Windows 7 utility.

The VPN connects fine. I can see that I'm connected on both sides of the VPN.

However, when I go to `Start>Run>\\192.168.13.201\P`, I cannot see any files. Troubleshooting the error returns "The remote device or resource won't accept the connection".

I have unchecked the "`Use gateway on remote side`" setting.

I have port forwarded 1723 to my client PC.

I have another Windows 7 client that can connect just fine.

**I do not care about WINS. I am trying to connect to straight IP.**

`192.168.13.201` is the server and `192.168.13.202` is the client

I have compared all settings between the working and broken clients, and I am at a loss as to why this is not working.

Some additional troubleshooting info:

```
C:\Users\Pat>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


PPP adapter VPN HQ:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.13.202
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home.int
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : <removed>
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.13
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Pinging seems ok:

```
C:\Users\Pat>ping 192.168.13.201

Pinging 192.168.13.201 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.13.201: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.13.201: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.13.201: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.13.201: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.13.201:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 20ms, Maximum = 25ms, Average = 22ms

C:\Users\Pat>ping 192.168.13.202

Pinging 192.168.13.202 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.13.202: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.13.202: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.13.202: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.13.202: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.13.202:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

[image: Troubleshooting result]

Routing table with VPN connected:

```
C:\Users\Pat>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 25...........................VPN HQ
 10...d8 50 e6 4e ed 21 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
 15...08 00 27 00 24 08 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.13     20
    71.235.246.15  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.13     21
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.13    276
     192.168.0.13  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.13    276
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.13    276
     192.168.13.0    255.255.255.0   192.168.13.201   192.168.13.202     21
   192.168.13.202  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.13.202    276
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.13    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.13.202    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.13    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.13.202    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 15    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 10    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 15    276 fe80::248a:9aa4:1ba5:b8b9/128
                                    On-link
 10    276 fe80::6d58:c0b:2b2a:f6a0/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 15    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 10    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Users\Pat>
```

Comment: How is the VPN server setup?  Is there any firewall on the VPN device?  Is there any firewall on the server that is blocking access?

Comment: The VPN "server" is really a Windows XP device (yeah; I know.) - As part of my testing, I disabled the firewall there, and there was no change in the behavior above. Client A works, whereas this Client B is not working (in the same environment; side-by-side).

Comment: Please post your routing table.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Question updated with `route print`

Comment: Try adding a $ to the path after the drive letter \\192.168.13.201\P$

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames Good point, I tried that and it still fails. It's not a hidden share (which the $ usually means), and I don't have to do that on "Client A" which is the working one.

Comment: Here is the dummy check, do you have the drive shared... and is it looking for credentials that exist on both computers?

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames Yep, the drive is shared. It is not looking for credentials. Sharing security is Everyone can change files. It was working on Client B, but only for a few minutes. Now I cannot get it to show up again.

Comment: Now, this might be dumb, so I apologize in advance, but what about the fact that your PPP connection is not on the same subnet as your ethernet network?  As a matter of fact, the subnet mask for your PPP connection only allows for a single IP address.  Would it help if that Point-To-Point link shared the same subnet?

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames Yeah, I have it setup as a /32 as I only need to access the 1 device on the network. The strange thing is, this exact setup is working (with the split networking). I wonder if I should delete this VPN adapter, and start fresh. I must be missing a checkbox or something.

Comment: is your port forwarding TCP or UDP or both?

Comment: Found the problem. Apparently I named this new PC, the exact same name as my old one. The IPs are different, but the duplicate name was not happy. Wow, this was a weird one. End goal, it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, I found that I named this new PC the exact same name as the old PC.

A weird one, but glad I found it. Windows Event Viewer clued me in:

`The server could not bind to the transport \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{guid} because another computer on the network has the same name.  The server could not start.`

Renaming the PC and rebooting **everything** helped clear up the problem.

Thanks for everyone's help in the comments.